# Problems with an slider i'm developing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a full page slider. This is what i'm trying to build:

1. I declare this variables in the .js file:

> ```
> var current = 0; // This is the id that is shown
> var total = $('.post').length; // Total number of divs
> ```

**The main structure of the html**

```
<div class="controller">
    <a href="#" id="previous_slide"></a>
    <a href="#" id="next_slide"></a>
</div>

<ul id="slider">

    <li class="post" id="0"> 
       // Content
    </li>

    <li class="post" id="1"> 
       // Content
    </li>

</ul>
```

When the user clicks on "previous_slide" or "next_slide" button, the jquery calls to the ***go_slide()*** function and **pass by reference** an string depending or the action (go_before or go_after).

```
$("#previous_slide").click( go_slide("go_before") );
$("#next_slide").click( go_slide("go_after") );

function go_slide(action_name)
{
    var prev = current - 1;
    var next = current +1;

    if (action_name == "go_before") 
    {
        $('#'+current).hide();
        $('#'+previous).show():
        current--; // Updates the value of current slide
    }
    else if(action_name == "go_after")
    {
        $('#'+current).hide();
        $('#'+next).show():
        current++; // Updates the value of current slide
    }
}
```

What can i do to run correct the code??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you tell us what exactly did not work ?

Comment: need to wrap your click handlers in anonymous functions. You aren't passing references when you include parenthesis and arguments

Comment: @Frederik.L Thanks for the welcoming! doesn't work the hole script. I think the problem is with the functions parameters... But don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your reply. I'm a bit lost with jquery in that part... How can i do this??.

Comment: start here  http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally i use like this：

```
$("#previous_slide").click( function() { go_slide("go_before") } );
$("#next_slide").click( function() {go_slide("go_after") } );
```

Comment: Would it be possible to explain why this code works but OP's code does not?

Comment: @dwq88397 Yes! It works!! Would be great if you can explain me why what did you do here. Thank you!

Comment: (+1) partial answer : .click() needs a function as an handler.. a function call isn't a function, but an anonymous function is ! I'll let dwq explain in more details.

Comment: Glad that helped! And er..i also learned it from jQuery API..[link](http://api.jquery.com/click/).As frederik sayed,you passed in a function call which actually equal to it's result(undefined) and it already excuted

Comment: Thank you so much guys! That's help me out a lot